# Storm control problem with Juniper switch configuration (EX2300)

Tags: juniper, switching, networking, juniper-ex

I am new with Juniper and generally new with switch configuration. Probably screwed up a lot but anyways, I will share my configuration right after I say what I want. I am getting Internet on **configured** ports, so that side works, however, I need a better way to configure them all, add storm-control to them and I have no idea how to do that. I also need your advice if anything is missing. I have configured the switch like this:

> ### Last changed: 2021-10-26 09:42:54 CEST version 20.4R3.8; system {
>
> ```
> host-name Juniper-Rechts;
> root-authentication {
>     encrypted-password "insert random gibberish";
> }
> services {
>     ssh {
>         root-login allow;
>         protocol-version v2;
>     }
>     netconf {
>         ssh;
>     }
>     dhcp-local-server {
>         traceoptions {
>             file jdhcplog;
>             flag all;
>         }
>     }
>     web-management {
>         http;
>     }
> }
> domain-name gov.intra;
> domain-search gov.intra;
> backup-router 10.13.69.1;
> time-zone Europe/Berlin;
> name-server {
>     10.5.8.11;
>     10.5.8.10;
> }
> syslog {
>     user * {
>         any emergency;
>     }
>     file messages {
>         any notice;
>         authorization info;
>     }
> }
> ntp {
>     server 162.159.200.123 prefer;
> } } interfaces {
> ge-0/0/0 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/1 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/2 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/3 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/4 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/5 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/6 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/7 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/8 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/9 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/10 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/11 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/12 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/13 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/14 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/15 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/16 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/17 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/18 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/19 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/20 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/21 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/22 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/23 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/24 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/25 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/26 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/27 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/28 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/29 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/30 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/31 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/32 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/33 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/34 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/35 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/36 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/37 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/38 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/39 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/40 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/41 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/42 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/43 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/44 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/45 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/46 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ge-0/0/47 {
>     apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
>         Default;
>     }
>     speed auto;
>     link-mode full-duplex;
>     ether-options {
>         auto-negotiation;
>         no-flow-control;
>     }
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             interface-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members default;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> vme {
>     unit 0 {
>         family inet {
>             address 10.13.69.94/24;
>         }
>     }
> } } forwarding-options {
> storm-control-profiles sc {
>     all {
>         bandwidth-level 15000;
>     }
> } } access {
> address-assignment {
>     pool DHCP-Desno {
>         family inet {
>             network 10.13.69.0/24;
>             range limited {
>                 low 10.13.69.2;
>                 high 10.13.69.253;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> } } routing-options {
> static {
>     route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 10.13.69.1;
> } } protocols {
> lldp {
>     interface all;
> }
> lldp-med {
>     interface all;
> }
> igmp-snooping {
>     vlan all;
> } } switch-options {
> voip {
>     interface ge-0/0/0.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/1.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/2.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/3.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/4.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/5.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/6.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/7.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/8.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/9.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/10.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/11.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/12.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/13.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/14.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/15.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/16.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/17.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/18.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/19.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/20.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/21.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/22.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/23.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/24.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/25.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/26.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/27.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/28.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/29.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/30.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/31.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/32.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/33.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/34.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/35.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/36.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/37.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/38.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/39.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/40.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/41.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/42.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/43.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/44.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/45.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/46.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
>     interface ge-0/0/47.0 {
>         vlan mgmt;
>     }
> } } vlans {
> default {
>     vlan-id 1;
> }
> mgmt {
>     description "MANAGEMENT PORT";
>     vlan-id 100;
> } }
> ```

Please give me assistance on what to do. I am completely lost, it's been days.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
system {
    host-name Juniper-Rechts;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "insert random gibberish";
    }
    services {
        ssh {
            root-login allow;
            protocol-version v2;
        }
        netconf {
            ssh;
        }
        dhcp-local-server {
            traceoptions {
                file jdhcplog;
                flag all;
            }
        }
        web-management {
            http;
        }
    }
    domain-name gov.intra;
    domain-search gov.intra;
    backup-router 10.13.69.1;
    time-zone Europe/Berlin;
    name-server {
        10.5.8.11;
        10.5.8.10;
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
    }
    ntp {
        server 162.159.200.123 prefer;
    }
}

interfaces {
    apply-macro juniper-port-profile {
        Default;
    }
    
    ge-0/0/0 {
        speed auto;
        link-mode full-duplex;
        ether-options {
            auto-negotiation;
            no-flow-control;
        }
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members default;
                }
            }
        }
        storm-control {
            default-profile;
        }
    }
    
    ge-0/0/1 {
        speed auto;
        link-mode full-duplex;
        ether-options {
            auto-negotiation;
            no-flow-control;
        }
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members default;
                }
            }
        }
        storm-control {
            default-profile;
        }
    }
    
    ge-0/0/2 {
        speed auto;
        link-mode full-duplex;
        ether-options {
            auto-negotiation;
            no-flow-control;
        }
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members default;
                }
            }
        }
        storm-control {
            default-profile;
        }
    }
    
    // Repeat the above block for other interfaces (ge-0/0/3 to ge-0/0/21)
}

protocols {
    lldp {
        interface all;
    }
    rstp;
    igmp-snooping;
    storm-control {
        profile default-profile {
            bandwidth-level 75;
        }
    }
}
```

Modify each interface configuration to include storm-control and assign them to the desired VLANs